# Can I perform multiclass classification when the number of features is less than the number of targets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is it possible to perform multiclass classification on data where the number of features is less than the number of target variables? Do you have any suggestions on how to address a problem where I have 2000 target variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. It only depends if those features are informative enough for the task at hand. In order to better understand the phenomenon, you can imagine 2 features displayed as points in a 2D plane. The number of possible target classes goes up to the number of clusters you can find in that plane.

About the suggestion, I can only recommend the utilisation of a non-linear classifier.